# HTML Contenteditable: Limit edit operations and copy updated text

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, contenteditable, dom-events, keyevent

I have a `contenteditable` `p` element. I'd like to limit the possible edit operations to inserting and deleting commas. I also want to copy the updated contents to another `div`. These two goals seem to be hard to combine:

- It seems I have to listen for `keydown` events to prevent the text from changing using `event.preventDefault()` if any other key than backspace or comma was pressed. When I listen for `keyup`, `event.preventDefault()` is executed too late and the content is updated regardless which key was pressed.
- But I may need to wait for `keyup` to update the paragraphs's content so that I can copy the text. If I use `keydown`, I get the original text.

I'm using Vue. In the HTML code, `@keydown='evaluate($event)'` simply attaches a listener and allow access to the event variable using.

*Edit: This is my original code, also see the snippet (without Vue) below.*

**HTML**

```
<p @keydown='evaluate($event)' id='text' contenteditable>
    Some text
</p>
```

**JS**

```
evaluate: function(storeResponse = true, event) {

    // Stop if any key except comma or backspace was pressed. Only works well with keydown.
    if (! [',', 'Backspace'].includes (event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, copy the updated content. Only works well with keyup.
    let textContent = document.getElementById('text').textContent;

    // Paste updated content to another p
    document.getElementById('original-text').innerText = textContent;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keydown', evaluate);

function evaluate() {
  // Stop if any key except comma or backspace was pressed.
  // Only works well with keydown.
  if (![',', 'Backspace'].includes(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  // Otherwise, copy the updated content. Only works well with keyup.
  let textContent = document.getElementById('text').textContent;

  // I need to paste the updated content to another div, but just log it for this snippet
  console.log(textContent);
}
```

```html
<p @keydown='evaluate' id='text' contenteditable>
  Some text
</p>
```

Is there an elegant way to limit possible edit operations *and* get the updated text?

Comment: Not quite sure what the end result should be like. Can you make a quick example of expected input and output?

Comment: I added a code snippet. Try adding a few commas inside `#text`, one by one: After inserting one comma, 'Some text' is logged, after inserting two commas 'Some text,' is logged etc.. The output is always one edit operation behind.

Comment: For the moment, I listen for both keydown events (the handler calls `preventDefault()`unless comma or backspace where pressed) and keyup events (the handler copies the updated text). I'm not sure whether spreading this functionality over separate event handlers will work out eventually as I still need to add some checking (as of now, users can only _add_  commas, but _delete_ any character).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that in a single event:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    content: ''
  }),

  methods: {
    evaluate(event) {
      // Stop if any key except comma or backspace was pressed. Only works well with keydown.
      if (![',', 'Backspace'].includes(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

      // Otherwise, copy the updated content.
      const el = event.target;

      // Paste updated content to another p
      this.content = el.textContent;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p @keydown='evaluate' contenteditable>
    Start typing...
  </p>

  <br />
 
  <p v-text="content">
    Updated text goes here.
  </p>
</div>
```

#### Quick tip:

Passing a method name without any argument and enclosing parens automatically passes the associated [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) data object to the method under the hood, if keyboard event is performed, then a [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) data object will be passed to the method.

So, the following lines are actually equivalent:

```html
<p @keydown='evaluate($event)'></p>

<!-- Or -->

<p @keydown='evaluate'></p>
```

Comment: I'm afraid your answer doesn't work. Try inserting exactly one comma and have a look at the output. I've written about this in the second bullet point in my question as well as in the code comments. Thanks for for quick tip, I wasn't aware of this!

Comment: So delete/backspace key should only delete the commas?

Comment: Yes. But in your answer, there's another problem: When pressing the comma key, the p with _v-text="content"_ still shows _Start typing..._. The output is always one edit operation behind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet based on Yom S.'s answer.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    content: ''
  }),

  methods: {
    /**
     * Checks whether the keypress should be processed.
     */
    checkKey: function() {
        // Users may only navigate or enter/delete commas
        let permittedKeys = [
            ',',
            'Backspace',
            'ArrowLeft',
            'ArrowRight',
            'ArrowDown',
            'ArrowUp'
        ];

        if (! permittedKeys.includes (event.key)) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    evaluate(event) {
      // Stop if any key except comma or backspace was pressed. Only works well with keydown.
      if (![',', 'Backspace'].includes(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

      // Otherwise, copy the updated content.
      const el = event.target;

      // Paste updated content to another p
      this.content = el.textContent;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p @keydown='checkKey' @keyup='evaluate' contenteditable>
    Start typing...
  </p>

  <br />
 
  <p v-text="content">
    Updated text goes here.
  </p>
</div>
```

When you run the snippet, you'll see it's still possible to delete other characters than commas. AFAIK, it's not possible to get the deleted character from the key events, so the only chance seems to be undoing such deletions. To do so, I remove all commas from both the edited text and the previous version. If these strings are not identical, I copy the previous version to the `contenteditable` element.